# Couchbase view for document deletion

Tags: java, spring, couchbase

I'm using couchbase server with spring data. Also for the crud operations I'm using spring `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`. I want to remove User documents which have same domain name. domain is a attribute of User pojo. I was able to fetch the documents based on the domain attribute value.

This is the my repo class.

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>{

    List<User> findByDomain(Query query);

    void deleteByDomain(Query query);

}
```

Also the view for findByDomain is,

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if (doc._class == "com.link.pojo.User") {
    emit(doc.domain, null);
  }
}
```

This is working for get all documents in same domain name. So I used the same view for deleteByDomain() function. It gives me an error.Seems like this view only work for fetch data. How can I remove documents which in same domain? Thanks.

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.util.ArrayList<?> to type void for value '[com.link.pojo.User@21dfd606, com.link.pojo.User@6e5c3549, com.link.pojo.User@67ae8439, com.link.pojo.User@726aef5c]'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type java.util.ArrayList<?> to type void
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:176)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutionResultHandler.postProcessInvocationResult(QueryExecutionResultHandler.java:75)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view needs to emit the object ID for each object in the view. Then take that array of IDs and for each one, call a delete on each of those IDs. If it fits your use case, a better way and should reduce the load on your cluster if there are a lot to delete is to set a random TTL between now and X hours/days/whatever on each object to be deleted. Then the Couchbase server will delete them as they are expired in a staggered fashion. If you need them deleted as soon as possible, then obviously use the delete call on the object IDs.